# How do I get installed java versions?

Tags: java, c#, installation

I'm creating an intallation for my program and I want to verify that there is a java version installed before installing.

How do I know what java versions are installed on the pc? I created the intallation with wpf.

EDIT:
If I find there isn't java installed, I want to intall it together with my program. So I need to be able to get the java version with c# code.

Comment: What installer are you using?

Comment: You could just call `java -version` to get the default installation. There could be any number of other installations in any directory though.